# hover over the button in android

Tags: android

Is there anyway to change the appearance of a button when the user clicks on it? for example change the color or make it dark?  Like using CSS in ASP.net to hover over a word or a link.

Comment: Hover means that you'd change the appearance of the button _before_ it's clicked. This is used on devices with a mouse, where the mouse pointer 'hovers' above the button and you give a visible feedback so the user knows that she'S aiming at the right place. With Android and it's touch centered interface that's not possible as it cannot detect your finger before you've touched the button and thus already clicked it.

Comment: so is there a way to change its color when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: Yes, the regular Button widget does this anyway. If you want your own button graphics, you'll have to use a StateList drawable, as Ralgha said in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Save this as a drawable xml resource and set this as a background of your button. Please explore the other options of Selector class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#BB908C8B" android:startColor="#BB908C8B" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="9dp" android:topRightRadius="9dp" />
    </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#BB54504F" android:startColor="#BB54504F" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="9dp" android:topRightRadius="9dp" />
    </shape></item>
</selector>
```

Look at the link http://android.onyou.ch/2011/01/25/simple-custom-button-using-a-selector-xml-layout/

Answer (score 0):

I believe [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) is what you're looking for.